# C# List<> property to XML

Tags: c#

Got this code...

```
public class CardLogos
{
    [XmlElement("Card")]
    public string Card { get; set; }
}

public class P_M
{
    [XmlElement("Cards")]
    public List<CardLogos> Cards { get; set; }
}
```

Trying to build the Cards property:

```
pm = new P_M();
...Other property setting happens here
pm.Cards = new List<CardLogos>();
pm.Cards.Add(new CardLogos() {Card="VISA"});
pm.Cards.Add(new CardLogos() {Card="AMEX"});
pm.Cards.Add(new CardLogos() {Card="DISCOVER"});
```

But the serialized XML comes out like this:

```
<P_M>
    <Other Properties>
    <Cards>
        <Card>VISA</Card>
    </Cards>
    <Cards>
        <Card>AMEX</Card>
    </Cards>
    <Cards>
        <Card>DISCOVER</Card>
    </Cards>
</P_M>
```

How can I make it come out like this:

```
<P_M>
    <Other Properties>
    <Cards>
        <Card>VISA</Card>
        <Card>AMEX</Card>
        <Card>DISCOVER</Card>
    </Cards>
</P_M>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`XmlArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute?view=net-7.0) and [`XmlArrayItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute?view=net-7.0) attributes and change `Cards` to a list of strings:

```cs
public class P_M
{
    [XmlArray("Cards")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName= "Card")]
    public List<string> Cards { get; set; }
}
```

This results in:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<P_M xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Cards>
    <Card>VISA</Card>
    <Card>AMEX</Card>
    <Card>DISCOVER</Card>
  </Cards>
</P_M>
```

[See this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lQmwO7).

Comment: I don't think this will solve his issue. I expect the `CardLogos` type has other important properties that are omitted from the question for brevity, such that a `List<string>` is not an option.

Comment: Not exactly correct. Cards is a property of P_M, Can't use `[XmlType(TypeName = "Cards")]` on CardLogos

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Perhaps you're right, let's hope it'll be clarified then. I would assume if this wasn't an option, that OP would have provided the code he used to perform the serialization instead.

Comment: The serialization is straight using XMLSerializer, nothing special

Comment: @MB34 Can you elaborate why this is not a possible solution?

Comment: Because Cards is a property of P_M, you neglected P_M in your solution. Just updated the code sample showing

Comment: @MB34 Excuse me for not understanding, but `P_M` is in my answer as well as the `Cards` property, so I don't see what I'm neglecting. Are you telling me that `P_M` and `CardLogos` cannot be modified in any way? If so, I don't believe what you're asking is possible

Comment: @MB34 Perhaps I've figured out what you mean now. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class P_M
{
    [XmlArray("Cards")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName= "Card")]
    public List<CardLogos> Cards { get; set; }
}

public class CardLogos
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Card { get; set; }
}
```

It preserves all of the original types, without needing to reduce down to a `List<string>`.  Any other properties you may have in `CardLogos` can be skipped over with `XmlIngore` attributes.